# SQL Server Cross-Database, Cross-Server Relationships

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In SQL Server are these things possible

1. Writing a select query which references tables from different databases on the same server?
2. Writing a select query which references tables from different databases on different servers?
3. Having a primary key, foreign key relationship between tables in different databases on the same server?
4. Having a primary key, foreign key relationship between tables in different databases on different servers?

THanks,

Sachin

Comment: Yes, yes, no, no. But you might be able to emulate the same thing with triggers for 3 & 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 2 = yes

3 & 4 = no

SQL Server cannot maintain referential integrity between tables in different databases, so also different servers.

But, you can join these tables in a query using the construct `server.database.schema.table`

[edit] assuming you are using linked servers, of course [/edit]

There is good info on configuring linked servers [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)